# how to convert north south direction to + or - symbol objective c

Tags: objective-c, location, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have a cordinate with N/S and E/W symbol. I need to convert it to `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. I have degrees string and direction string separately need to know how to convert them.

Example:

```
longitude: @"80.26416666666667"
longitude direction: @"E"
latitude: @"13.05866666666667"
latitude direction: @"N"
```

How to convert N/E and W/S to original float values with positive or negative magnitude

Comment: please provide a comment while down voting so that I ca understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting strings to numbers can be done with methods from `NSString`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *longitudeStr = @"80.26416666666667";
        NSString *longitudeCardinalDirection = @"E";
        NSString *latitudeStr = @"13.05866666666667";
        NSString *latitudeCardinalDirection = @"N";

        CLLocationDegrees longitude = [longitudeStr doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees latitude = [latitudeStr doubleValue];

        if ([longitudeCardinalDirection isEqualToString:@"W"]) longitude *= -1;
        if ([latitudeCardinalDirection isEqualToString:@"S"]) latitude *= -1;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

        NSLog(@"%f, %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have degrees string and direction string seperately need to know how to convert them